# Meteor - check if you have 2 versions of React running

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, npm, atmosphere

I've got React installed from atmosphere, and react-mixin from npm. It seems that react-mixin depends on react, so do I have 2 reacts running in my app? How can I check this - I don't see 'react' in my node_modules folder, however there is a react folder in node_modules when I open the sources tab...

Comment: Are you using Meteor 1.3 beta?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Meteor 1.3 beta? If so you should not use react from Atmosphere, but from `npm` (`npm i react react-dom`).

Likewise, if you are using Meteor 1.2.1 or bellow, you should not use packages directly from `npm`, but a wrapper from Atmosphere.

Comment: yes, I'm using Meteor 1.3, but also React from atmosphere because some packages depend on it... ;/

Comment: You should stick with one approach. Either try to migrate completely to npm or continue with atmosphere. I recommend the first one